# Adding objects using the mean (average) consistently

Tags: python, object

Say we have a class AverageNumber which when adding, finds the mean of the numbers being added:

```
class AverageNumber():

  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def __add__(self, other):
    average = ( self.value + other.value ) / 2 # This is the issue?
    return AverageNumber(average)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.value
```

This code is incorrect, as it fails to respect the additive commutative and associative properties that I was looking for, namely that:

average(1 + 3 + 2) = average(1 + 2 + 3) etc.

However this does not occur, as the above class adds two at a time.
The INCORRECT results are below:

```
>>> b = AverageNumber(1) + AverageNumber(3) + AverageNumber(2)
>>> b.value
2.0
>>> b = AverageNumber(1) + AverageNumber(2) + AverageNumber(3)
>>> b.value
2.25
```

My question is: How can I modify the code above to fix this issue?

Comment: Seems like your class will need to keep track of all the numbers that it is averaging, and re-compute the average when you add a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to track the number of numbers involved:

```
class AverageNumber():

  def __init__(self, value, count=1):
    self.value = value
    self.count = count

  def __add__(self, other):
    total = self.value + other.value
    count = self.count + other.count
    return AverageNumber(total, count)

  def getValue(self):
      return self.value / self.count



b = AverageNumber(1) + AverageNumber(3) + AverageNumber(2)
print(b.getValue())

b = AverageNumber(1) + AverageNumber(2) + AverageNumber(3)
print(b.getValue())

Output:
2.0
2.0
```